# why nano seconds have to use int instead of long in java

Tags: java, time, java-time, duration

I have been doing this exercise and this is the code

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Exercise31 {  
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2016, 9, 16, 0, 0);
        LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.now();
        int diffInNano = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime, dateTime2).getNano();
        long diffInSeconds = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime, dateTime2).getSeconds();
        long diffInMilli = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime, dateTime2).toMillis();
        long diffInMinutes = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime, dateTime2).toMinutes();
        long diffInHours = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime, dateTime2).toHours();
        System.out.printf("\nDifference is %d Hours, %d Minutes, %d Milli, %d Seconds and %d Nano\n\n",
                diffInHours, diffInMinutes, diffInMilli, diffInSeconds, diffInNano );
    }
}
```

Doesnt nanoseconds have to use long instead of int because the nanoseconds in the range?

Comment: Read the docs, it does not return the data in nanos but just the nano component.

Comment: @luk2302 is right, you probably confuse [`getNano()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#getNano--) with [`toNanos()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toNanos--)

Comment: I agree with you, that’s a slip in the design of the `Duration` class. The `getSeconds` and `getNanos` methods effectively expose implementation that should have been kept private. So they are confusing. Just ignore them.

Comment: @TasosP yeah i dont know what the differences is between them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because like [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#getNano--) says, we have a duration which consist of two fields, one is seconds and the other one is nanos.
So when you ask for duration between, you get 2 values :

`diff = seconds + nanos`

So in this case, nanos only count up to 999,999,999 (0.99... seconds), so integer is enough.

### So ...

If you need duration in nanos, you'll have to do something like this :

```
Long totalDurationNanos = (duration.getSeconds() * 1_000_000_000f) + duration.getNanos();
```

### EDIT :

As mentioned in comments, there is an easier way in your case :

Both

```
java.time.Duration.between(dateTime, dateTime2).toNanos()
```

And

```
ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(dateTime, dateTime2)
```

would output you long formatted nanosecond duration

Comment: I know, I just wanted to add more clarity by making it very explicit. Thus you are right, your solution is much more clearer. I 'll edit

Answer (score 1):

getNano() JavaDocs:

```
Returns:
the nanoseconds within the second part of the length of the duration, from 0 to 999,999,999
```